# Github windows, whole file shows change after commit.

Tags: windows, git

I am using the github windows app. I seem to be having problems with it showing what has changed and what hasn't. Before I commit it correctly shows only the changed lines, but after I commit, it shows that all the lines have changed in the file. Any way to get it to stop this?

It is quite annoying and any help would be appreciated. 
ps, i made sure that their are no line ending issues.

Comment: can you show a picture of how its showing please.?

Comment: Also note, that if I use the command line version, then i have no problems, it only occurs if i use the app.

Comment: An image of what's going on  http://i47.tinypic.com/t8axdj.png

Answer (score 5):

This is usual [`core.autocrlf`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html) issue (different setting in your clients and *definitely wrong* in Github client) - read "Formatting and Whitespace" topic and **core.autocrlf** part of it carefully

**PS**: you can test my statement using differ, which can ignore EOL-difference in compared files